# psycopg2 - how to deal with connection lost during the middle of data uploading

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe, psycopg2

I have a code that does the basics - insert the dataframe to postgres.

Say I have 10,000 rows of data to upload.
In the line "cur.executemany(query, data_values)", what if during this execution, the connection is lost after inserting 5000 rows. Is there a way to try reconnecting and continue at row 5001?

Thank you!

```
def insert_hp_csv_data_to_pgdb(df, table):
    
    # connect to db
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host="IP",
        database="database name",
        user="user",
        password="admin",
        port=5432)
        
        cur = connection.cursor()

        # Check if the table exists
        query = f"SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = %s)"
        cur.execute(query, (table,))
        table_exists = cur.fetchone()[0]

        if table_exists:
            print(f"The table '{table}' exists.")
        else:
            print(f"The table '{table}' does not exist.")
            raise Exception('create table in postgresql first with desired names. Make sure json names match them')

        # Use the mapping to determine the corresponding PostgreSQL column name
        postgresql_columns = []
        column_map = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),f'column_map/{table}.json') 
        with open(column_map, 'r') as file:
            map = json.load(file)
        for col in df.columns:
            postgresql_column_name = map.get(col, col)
            postgresql_columns.append(postgresql_column_name)
    
        # Generate the column names dynamically
        columns = ', '.join(postgresql_columns)
    
        # Generate the placeholders for the VALUES clause based on the number of columns
        placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(df.columns))

        # Create the INSERT query (will insert even if duplicate)
        query = f'''INSERT INTO analytical_db.{table}({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})''' # ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET {update_columns}'''

        # insert multiple row into dataframe
        # creates a list of tuples (data_values) where each tuple represents a row in your DataFrame. Then, the executemany method is used to insert all the rows with a single query. This can significantly improve the performance compared to inserting rows one by one.
        data_values = [tuple(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
        cur.executemany(query, data_values)
            
        connection.commit()
        print(f'data from {table} upload successfully')
                 
    except (Exception, Error) as error:
        print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
    finally:
        if (connection):
            cur.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: "Is there a way to try reconnecting and continue at row 5001?" Insert data in batches, committing at the end of each batch. Record the last successfully committed batch. When you reconnect, you can start with the subsequent one.

Comment: 1) Don't use `executemany()` for the reasons listed here [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers). 2) `cur.executemany(query, data_values) connection.commit()` means if the connection drops the changes won't be committed(especially as you call `connection.close()`, so nothing will be inserted. 3) See @larsks comment